# Webserver NSURL NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, webserver

Ok, I'm trying to get a file from my webserver. But I'm getting kinda confused about some stuff. When I use NSURL I can get my xml-file with an url like this: "localhost...../bla.xml".  But I'm also trying to test some things... Like... What will happen to my app if I have an open connection to the webserver, and I lose connection to internet? The above method with the NSURL, I haven't really established any connection where it always is connected right? or should I use be using NSURLConnection?

Maybe it's a little confusing, because I'm confused. I hope someone can give me some info I can research about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at NSURLConnection Class. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Create connection object and set a timeout value, if you lose the connection or the connection times out NSURLConnection delegate method: `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` gets called and you would be notified of that event.

You might also use `NSURLConnection` `sendSynchronousRequest` method, but its strongly discouraged to use that method as it would block the thread its running.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the content of a file? If so, you would use the following.

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLwithString:@"localhost/file.html"];
NSString *filecontents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

The NSString object `filecontents` would contain your string.

You wouldn't be able to loose connection in such a short time. If there is no connection, an error would be applied to `error`.

EDIT:
If you wanted to constantly stay connected to a server, that is a different story.
You have have to use C's `send()` and `recv()` functions, which you can read about [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).
I don't know much about it, and I'm learning it myself, so you should ask someone else on how to set up a server. But you will need to have another program running simultaniously.

Comment: I can access my file, but you are right. I cant lose the connection in such a short time. So I kinda want to establish a connection where I am "always" connected. Am I on the wrong track here?